# mock jdbctemplate with row mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, jdbctemplate

I need help mocking the jdbc template

```
this my method
public List<CountryRes> getEmpInfoList() throws AppException {     
          return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_COUNTRY_PREFIX, new RowMapper<CountryRes>() {
              public CountryRes mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                  Employee emp = new Employee();
                  emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("EPID"));
                  emp.setEmpName(rs.getString("EMPNAME"));                  
                  return countryRes;
              }
          });
```

and my test case

```
@Test
public void testEmp() throws AppException {

    Employee empres = new Employee();
    empres.setEmpId(12);
    empres.setEmpName("conti");
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    empList.add(empres);
    
    when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_GET_STORAGE_VALUE, new RowMapper<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              Employee emp = new Employee();
              emp.getEmpId(rs.getInt("EPID"));
              emp.getEmpName(rs.getString("EMPNAME"));                  
              return countryRes;
        }
    })).thenReturn(empList);

    when(resultSet.getInt("EPID")).thenReturn(12);
    when(emp.getEmpName(rs.getString("EMPNAME")).thenReturn("conti");

    // calling the method
    List<Emplyee> result = msSqlDB.getEmpInfoList(salesAgentIntr, tableName);
    
    
    assertEquals(12, result.get(0).getEmpId());       
}
```

when I am asserting result list(which I am returning) size is 0 ,can somebody help in identifying why result size is 0